# Compare forecast models accuracy

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, accuracy

I have a time series of number of visitors of an website for two years. I have to do the forecast of the number of visitors for the next semestre. To do so, I used three forecast models: ARIMA, auto_ARIMA and Holt Winters.

My problem is how to choose the most approprite model based on these accuracy function outputs:

accuracy function output for arima model:

[image]

accuracy function output for auto-arima model:

[image]

accuracy function output for Holt Winters model:

[image]

Here's the graph of the initial time series:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered incorporating daily effects/holiday effects and/or level shifts/local time trends while adjusting for errant data ?

Comment: Actually, No @IrishStat . I did a basic forecasting because I'm beginner in time series analysis. I added the plot of the time series to my question.

Comment: Your plot reveals and any serious analysis would reveal/uncover errant values which need to be treated/modified/accounted for otherwise you are "doomed to failure" . The basic problem is that parameter estimation  and model selection is flawed/affected leading to spurious conclusions using beginner/simple methods. Your analysis should not be too simple or overly complex .. just complex enough .

Comment: Yes, I understood you @IrishStat . I'll focus more in adjusting my inputs. Otherwise, what conclusion, In general, can I have from these accuracy outputs ?

Comment: I would say the results are mixed with no clear winner ....modelling is often an iterative procedure where the data is used to suggest a model via model identification procedures not simply based upon selecting from a a pre-specified set of ad hoc models, You might wish to share your data and the specifics of your hold-out strategy and see what some experts  might suggest.

Comment: Yes this is what I expected :/ . But as you said, I have to be more specific on my strategy. Thank you so much any way :)